# What are the Proto-Indo-European etymologies of “ihr” and “sie”?

Tags: etymology

As far as I know, there are some cognates about German and English personal pronouns, such as:

> German *ich* and English *I*
>
> German *du* and English *thou*
>
> German *wir* and English *we*
>
> German *ihr* (*you* pl.) and English *ye*

But I am confused with German *sie* (she, they) and *ihr* (her, their), because each word contains more than one meaning, and the cognates in English are unknown at least to me.

What is the Proto-Indo-European etymology of the German *sie* and German *ihr?*

Answer (score 2):

#### [Sie](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=sie&view=1)

Unlike the English *"they"* there is no Old Norse influence (***þeir***) in the etymology of *"sie"*. It is believed that it comes from Old Saxonian/Old High German ***thiu*** or ***siu*** thus not sharing a clear cut common etymology. This is probably different for the same spelt demonstrative pronoun *"sie"* that may share a same etymology with the English *she*.

#### [Ihr](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=ihr&view=1)

The situation is little different with *"ihr"* that shares a common etymology with Old Saxonian ***gī̌*** that became ***gē̌*** in Old English when used as personal pronoun plural. However today *ihr* is also used as a possessive pronoun derived from Old High German ***ira*** whereas the English analogon *"their"* again has its roots in Old Norse ***þeir***.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that English they is in connection with German die, die Leute, die Sachen etc (people, the things).

Their must be related to German deren: Die Eltern und deren Kinder (the parents and their children).

Them, I think, is related to German denen, in German only dative plural, in English dative and accusuative were no longer distinguished.

Her - in my view - is related with German ihr, two uses, a possessive adjective and a dative. In English /i:r/ has a form that begins with h, but the two words still sound similar and the function is the same:

Possessive: Susan and her brother - Susanne und ihr Bruder.
Dative: I promised Susan/her a present - Ich habe Susanne/ihr ein Geschenk versprochen.

I don't think that looking into PIE will bring any clarity.